# Built in Approval workflow not started on item edit event

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have requirement where when a user enter new item in a list first approver approves it then publisher approves it. Once publisher approves it the text will be visible to all.

I have used SharePoint built in Approval for that where I have set my workflow to start when new item created and item is changed.

When I Add new item workflow triggers and process of approving the item works fine and update the workflow status as completed.

But when I edit the same item, Workflow on item changed is not fired.

Can any one tell me how to set SharePoint built in workflow to start on new item created as well as item change events.

FYI: I have set content approval to "No" in my versioning settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of investigation I found that I have selected checkBox for "After the workflow is completed: Update the approval status (use this workflow to control content approval)".

Here I have not selected require content to be approved option for my list and for the same list I was updating approval status once workflow get completed.

What I observed is deselecting this option my workflow get fired successfully on new item created and Item change events.

Answer (score 1):

To make the checkbox work for you, you need to setup content approval enabled on the library level. If not, it is going to fail with an error in the backgound.